# Compare strings with Qt::MatchFlag

Tags: qt

Does Qt provide the method to determine matching of two strings?
For example:

```
 bool res = isMatched( "Hello World", "World", Qt::MatchContains );
```

Answer (score 2):

For determining if one string contains another string you can use `QString::contains` :

```
QString str = "Hello World";
bool res = str.contains("World", Qt:::CaseSensitive);    // returns true
```

You can also use `QString::compare` to compare strings. It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first string is less than, equal to, or greater than the second one :

```
int x = QString::compare(str1, str2, Qt::CaseInsensitive);
```

Comment: Of course, I can use QString methods to find out the strings matching. But I hope to get answer - is there a common method for this purpose. If there no such method - why?

Comment: What do you mean by "common method"? There are methods for comparing and checking existence of strings in `QString`. May be it is better to clarify more.

Comment: @YuriyVelichko If Nejat's answer is not what you want, perhaps you can specify your purpose in the question with details and explain what is **common method**? Additionally, you may take a look at [QStringMatcher](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstringmatcher.html#details) class.

Comment: Yuriy, answer is **Yes, Qt provides the method to determine matching of two strings** -- as described above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method which can compare strings using `Qt::MatchFlags`, because `Qt::MatchFlags` are intended only for a special purpose: find an item in a table.

These flags contains `Qt::MatchWrap` and `Qt::MatchRecursive` that have sense only for tables, not just for 2 strings.

Answer (score 0):

I needed this in a recent project and wrote a function that makes it easy to add to any program.  Here is a link to the code: http://sirspot.com/?p=324
and assuming nothing changes in the future...here is the code itself:

```
/** determine if the pattern matches the string using Qt::MatchFlags
    \param str the string
    \param pattern the pattern to find
    \param flags any combination of the follow Qt flags
                - Qt::MatchFixedString
                - Qt::MatchContains
                - Qt::MatchStartsWith
                - Qt::MatchEndsWith
                - Qt::MatchRegExp (overrides all flags above)
                - Qt::MatchCaseSensitive
    \returns true if the pattern is found in the string

    requires:
    #include <QString>
    #include <QRegularExpression>
    #include <QRegularExpressionMatch>

    Thank you for visiting sirspot.com
    This code is not guaranteed to work.
    Use at your own risk.
*/
static bool QString_Matches(
    const QString& str,
    const QString& pattern,
    const Qt::MatchFlags& flags = (Qt::MatchCaseSensitive | Qt::MatchFixedString))
{
    if(flags.testFlag(Qt::MatchRegExp) == true)
    {
        QRegularExpression::PatternOptions options = QRegularExpression::NoPatternOption;
        if(flags.testFlag(Qt::MatchCaseSensitive) == false)
        {
            options = QRegularExpression::CaseInsensitiveOption;
        }
        QRegularExpression regex(pattern, options);
        return regex.match(str).hasMatch();
    }
    else
    {
        Qt::CaseSensitivity cs = Qt::CaseSensitive;
        if(flags.testFlag(Qt::MatchCaseSensitive) == false)
        {
            cs = Qt::CaseInsensitive;
        }
        if(flags.testFlag(Qt::MatchContains) == true)
        {
            return str.contains(pattern, cs);
        }
        else
        {
            if(flags.testFlag(Qt::MatchStartsWith) == true)
            {
                if(str.startsWith(pattern, cs) == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if(flags.testFlag(Qt::MatchEndsWith) == true)
            {
                if(str.endsWith(pattern, cs) == true)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            if(flags.testFlag(Qt::MatchFixedString) == true)
            {
                return (str.compare(pattern, cs) == 0);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Happy String Matching!

Comment: Can you explain the advantage of your method compared to the other (shorter/easier) answers?

Comment: @m7913d There are 2 main advantages:
1. it uses established matching flags
2. it allows string matching criteria to be changed using a single function parameter.
3. it can be used without having to copy multiple lines of code to use different string matching methods

For example, I have a search box that I wanted the user to be able to select between "starts with" "exact match" and "regular expression" so by writing this generic string matching function I can simply pass a different set of flags to my search algorithm and it changes how the search is performed.